# Access Directory over HTTP

Tags: ssh, remote, sftp, http

I have been looking for a secure way to access a specific directory outside of my local network, I would like to access my files on my fedora server at home from my school network, which rules out SFTP(as those kinds of connections are blocked). I would also like it to be as secure as possible. I have tried OwnCloud, but I found it didn't sync very well when I copied a file to it from the command line.

Comment: If you are a relative novice you might try [teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/), free for personal use. It requires no firewall changes at home.

Answer (score 2):

The most simple thing you could try is to let your ssh server listen on https port too. (In case you don't already have a https web server running.)

Add these lines to your /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Port 22
Port 443
```

Restart ssh server. And try:

```
sftp -P 433 your-server
```